Missing timestamp information exported GEE .tif file
I am trying to export GEOS-CF information to my google drive. This works, however I do not see any associated timestamp information in the metadata using python or ArcGIS. This is supposed to be Temp, wind direction, and RH over a state for a month. I need to be able to visualize the daily values, and to be able to analyze by date.
// Define date range
var date_1 = "2023-09-01";
var date_2 = "2023-10-01";

// Define ROI based on 2018 census data 
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('STATEFP', '26')); // Michigan FIPS code

// Import collections
var col = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GEOS-CF/v1/fcst/tavg1hr')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .filterDate(date_1, date_2)
  .select(['T', 'U', 'V', 'RH'])
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.set('timestamp', image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss'));
  }); // Select all three bands at once (Temp, Eastward and Northward Wind, RH)

print(col);

// Get version number (ingestion timestamp as microseconds since Unix epoch).
var version = col.get('system:version');
print('Version:', version);  // ee.Number
print('Version (as ingestion date):',
      ee.Date(ee.Number(version).divide(1000)));  // ee.Date

// Get the timestamp and convert it to a date.
var date = ee.Date(col.get('system:time_start'));
print('Timestamp:', date);  // ee.Date

// Calculate mean and max for each variable
var meanValues = col.mean().set({
  'start_time': col.first().get('timestamp'),
  'end_time': col.sort('system:time_start', false).first().get('timestamp')
});

var maxValues = col.max().set({
  'start_time': col.first().get('timestamp'),
  'end_time': col.sort('system:time_start', false).first().get('timestamp')
});

print(meanValues); 
// Define visualization parameters for temperature
var tempVisParams = {
  bands: ['T'],
  min: 270,
  max: 300,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

// Add the mean temperature layer to the map
Map.centerObject(ROI, 7);
Map.addLayer(meanValues.select('T').clip(ROI), tempVisParams, 'Mean Temperature');

var meanValuesWithMetadata = meanValues.set({
  'system:time_start': meanValues.get('start_time'),
  'system:time_end': meanValues.get('end_time')
});

var maxValuesWithMetadata = maxValues.set({
  'system:time_start': maxValues.get('start_time'),
  'system:time_end': maxValues.get('end_time')
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: meanValuesWithMetadata.clip(ROI),
  description: 'GEOS_CF_Mean_' + date_1 + '_to_' + date_2,
  fileNamePrefix: 'GEOS_CF_Mean_' + date_1 + '_to_' + date_2 + '_' + 
                  meanValues.get('start_time').getInfo() + '_to_' + 
                  meanValues.get('end_time').getInfo(),
  scale: 5000,
  folder: 'GEE',
  region: ROI,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maxValuesWithMetadata.clip(ROI),
  description: 'GEOS_CF_Max_' + date_1 + '_to_' + date_2,
  fileNamePrefix: 'GEOS_CF_Max_' + date_1 + '_to_' + date_2 + '_' + 
                  maxValues.get('start_time').getInfo() + '_to_' + 
                  maxValues.get('end_time').getInfo(),
  scale: 5000,
  folder: 'GEE',
  region: ROI,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

